# URL replace with anchor, not replacing existing anchors

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building code matching and replacing several types of patterns (bbCode). One of the matches I'm trying to make, is [url=http:example.com] replacing all with anchor links. I'm also trying to match and replace plain textual urls with anchor links. And the combination of these two is where I'm running in to some trouble.

Since my routine is recursive, matching and replacing the entire text each run, I'm having trouble NOT replacing urls already contained in anchors.

This is the recursive routine I'm running:

```
if(text.search(p.pattern) !== -1) {
    text = text.replace(p.pattern, p.replace);
}
```

This is my regexp for plain urls so far:

```
/(?!href="|>)(ht|f)tps?:\/\/.*?(?=\s|$)/ig
```

And URLs can start with http or https or ftp or ftps, and contain whatever text afterwards, ending with whitespace or a punctuation mark (. / ! / ? / ,)

Just to be absolutely clear, I'm using this as a test for matches:

Should match:

- http://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com/test
- http://example.com/test
- www.example.com/test

Should not match

- <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com </a>
- <a href="http://www.example.com/test">http://www.example.com/test </a>
- <a href="http://example.com/test">http://example.com/test </a>
- <a href="www.example.com/test">www.example.com/test </a>

I would really appretiate any help I can get here.

**EDIT**
The first accepted solution by jkshah below does have some flaws. For instance, it will match

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/test.jpg">
```

The comments in Jerry's solution however did make me want to try it again, and that solution solved this issue as well. I therefore accepted that solution instead. Thank you all for your kind help on this. :)

Comment: Now this is very generic problem. you will find more bugs with one or the other regex as you apply to wider range of samples. You will have to adjust regex accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
/(?:(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/|www)[^<>\]]+?(?![^<>\]]*([>]|<\/))(?=[\s!,?\]]|$)/gm
```

And then trim the dots at the end if any.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eR2fX6)

Though if the link contains more punctuations, it might cause some issues... I would then suggest capturing the link first, then remove the trailing punctuations with a second replace.

`[^<>\]]+` will match every character except `<`, `>` and `]`

`(?![^<>\]]*([>]|<\/))` prevents the matching of a link between html tags.

`(?=[\s!,?\]]|$)` is for the punctuations and whitespace.

Comment: I'm sorry, that did not match any of the tests I'm running. 
I'm running the match through javascript using
text.replace(p.pattern, p.replace);

I've redefined the question above to include my match tests, and the routine I'm running to find my matches.

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen If you're testing them line by line, there shouldn't be any problem, but I guess I could add a version for a full page or something... updated regex.

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen How are you planning to identify the 4th link in your question? Would it start with `www`?

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen are you escaping the special characters used in the regular expression? There are so many of those. Try this  - /(?:ht|f)tps?:\\/\\/[^\x3C\\]]+?(?![^\x3E\\]]*[\x3E])(?=[\\s!,?\\]]|$)/g

Comment: This did not work on replace: http://regex101.com/r/mB7sF6
It matches alright though...

Comment: @Jerry: Yes, either http and/or www should be present for it to qualify as a link.

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen Why did you use `$1`? There's no capture group. You therefore use `$&`. See: http://regex101.com/r/rP7sZ4. Also, my regex allows replacement anywhere in any text. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsBwz/1/) comparing my regex (first) and the one you accepted.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just to make for consistency in my patterns, I added parentheses around the regexp to make a capture group.  This solution actually also solved my problem with <img src="http://www.example.com/test.jpg"> as well. I will therefore set this solution as the accepted one instead. Thank you. :)

Comment: this regex doesn't match `<b>http://www.example.com</b>` and I believe this should not be the case

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen Okay, you're welcome :). jkshah If that's an issue, the regex can be adapted easily with a few additions to character classes and some small tweaks.

Comment: I liked this solution, it seemed to work well. With one exception, '-' and '_' is quite common in a url so I extended it slightly:

`https://regex101.com/r/kL3iL7/11`

Comment: This one doesn't include parameters (?par=val)

Comment: @RudiStrydom Not sure what you mean, it does match `-` and `_`, but ok

Comment: @letie Yes, it stops at `?` because OP specified the url could stop at a `?`, I assume so that the match won't include a question mark that isn't part of the url but of a sentence. You can remove it from the lookahead if needed (near the end, remove the `?` inside the square brackets from `(?=[\s!,?\]]|$)`)

Answer (score 1):

Following regex should work. It's giving desired result on your sample inputs.

```
/((?:(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/|www)[^\s,?!]+(?!.*<\/a>))/gm
```

See it in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/xL0hC6)

`(?!.*<\/a>)` - Negative lookahead for anchor

Matching content will be stored in `$1` and can be used in replace string.

**EDIT**

To not match content with `<img src ..` following can be used

```
(^(?!.*<img\s+src)(?:(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/|www)[^\s,?!]+(?!.*<\/a>))
```

Comment: For replace you need to capture entire regex with brackets. Check [here](http://regex101.com/r/aM5bH1)

Comment: Ran in to a bit of trouble in this regexp. It actually also matched <img src="http://www.example.com/test.jpg"> and it resultet in <img src="<a href="http://www.example.com/test.jpg">http://www.example.com/test.jpg</a>">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38245/discussion-between-oystein-amundsen-and-jkshah)

Comment: This does not include parameters (?par=val)

Answer (score 0):

can `p.replace` be a function? if so:

```
var text = 'http://www.example.com \n' +
           'http://www.example.com/test \n' +
           'http://example.com/test \n' +
           'www.example.com/test \n' +
           '<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com </a>\n' +
           '<a href="http://www.example.com/test">http://www.example.com/test </a>\n' +
           '<a href="http://example.com/test">http://example.com/test </a>\n' +
           '<a href="www.example.com/test">www.example.com/test </a>';
var p = {
    flag: true,
    pattern: /(<a[^<]*<\/a>)|((ht|f)tps?:\/\/|www\.).*?(?=\s|$)/ig,
    replace: function ($0, $1) {
                 if ($1) {
                     return $0;
                 } else {
                     p.flag = true;
                     return "construct replacement string here";
                 }
    }
};
while(p.flag){
    p.flag = false;
    text = text.replace(p.pattern, p.replace);
}
```

The part of the regex I added is `(<a[^<]*<\/a>)|` to check if the url is anywhere inside an anchor, if so then the replacement function ignores it.

If you want to avoid the url inside `<a href="...">` but other urls inside the anchor are to be replaced, then change `(<a[^<]*<\/a>)|` to `(<a[^>]*>)|`

Comment: I really would like it to NOT be a function, as I know that it is possible to filter away all matches already contained in anchors.

Comment: ... and your provided regexp matches every url, even those already contained in links. But I guess that was the idea, since you fine tune your match inside the p.replace function.