# URL matching regexp does not work all the time

Tags: javascript, regex

Could anyone with a good knowledge in regexp please explain to me why this regexp does not work on my example text? Or even better, come up with a regexp which actually work.

```
/((?:(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/|www)[^<>\]]+?(?![^<>\]]*([>]|<\/))(?=[\s!,\]]|$))/igm
```

The regexp is from this question: [URL replace with anchor, not replacing existing anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060460/url-replace-with-anchor-not-replacing-existing-anchors)

**Example text:**

```
"This is a simple test. \r\n\r\n" + 
"<u><b>A bold header with underscore:<\/b><\/u>\r\n" + 

"<i>THESE AREN'T TRANSFORMED. WHY??<\/i>\r\n" + 
"* http:\/\/www.example.net\/edit.php\r\n" + 
"* http:\/\/www.example.net\/test.php -> Some text\r\n" + 

"<i>THESE ARE:<\/i>\r\n" + 
"* http:\/\/www.example.net\/invite.php\r\n" + 
"* http:\/\/www.example.net\/forums.php\r\n"
```

[Complete example of problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/8baeS/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what i come up with :

```
((?:(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/|www)[^<>\]]+?(?![^<>\]]*(><\/))(?=[\s!,\]]|$))/igm
```

I tested it with your string and it is working...

I changed in your old regex `([>]|<\/)` to `(><\/)` ... You were doing an OR where you needed in that case to have the possibility to match all.

The output is as follow :

- www.example.net/edit.php\r\n"
- www.example.net/test.php
- www.example.net/invite.php\r\n"
- www.example.net/forums.php\r\n"

I hope this is what you needed.